# How do I delete an element from Array with click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I called it in a table, now I want to make a button, if you click on this button, the last array is deleted, but it doesn't work for me

```js
const show = document.querySelector("#show");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const table = document.querySelector("table")

var th = `
    <th> name</th> 
    <th> Alter</th> 
    <th> Beruf</th> 
    <th>  <div id="reverss"> Revers</div>  </th> `;

const schule = [

  {
    name: "Sam ",
    Alter: "80",
    Beruf: "Mediengestalter"
  },
  {
    name: "Alm",
    Alter: "26",
    Beruf: "PTA"
  },
  {
    name: "Chris",
    Alter: "18",
    Beruf: "AZUBI"
  },
  {
    name: "Smith",
    Alter: "4",
    Beruf: "OKA"
  }
]

table.innerHTML += th + schule.map(info =>
  ` <tr> <td>   ${info.name} </td> <td> ${info.Alter}</td> <td> ${info.Beruf} </td> </tr> <br>`

)

const rever = document.querySelector("#reverss").addEventListener("click", samee);

function samee() {

  schule.pop();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a HTML as well.

Comment: I think you'll want to set the `innerHTML` of the table again, after you `pop()` the value off the array. If what you want is your table to display the new array info after it's updated

Comment: A tried a reduced example of your code at jsfillde and it did work. Check the console for other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your array is not magically bound to the table markup. You'll have to change the table contents yourself (ore use a framework with data binding, like [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), [React](https://reactjs.org/), or [Angular](https://angularjs.org/)). Move the code that generates the table content to a function and call that once initially, and once after changing the array.
2. Semantically, **#reverss** should be a `<button>` element. If you want it to look like normal text (which is also not recommended, because users will not see that it is a clickable element), override styles using CSS.
3. You need to `join()` after the `map()`, otherwise, you'll have an implicit array-to-string conversion resulting in dangling commas after the table.
4. You don't need (and it's actually invalid markup) a `<br>` after a `<tr>`, the line break will happen automatically.
5. You forgot the `<tr></tr>` around the table headers. Also, the number of columns in the header row (4) should match the number of cells in each row (was: 3). Eithre add an empty colum to each row, or use the [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) attribute.

```js
const show = document.querySelector("#show");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const table = document.querySelector("table")

var th = `<tr>
    <th> name</th> 
    <th> Alter</th> 
    <th> Beruf</th> 
    <th>  <button id="reverss"> Revers</button>  </th>
  </tr>`;

const schule = [ {name: "Sam ",Alter: "80",Beruf: "Mediengestalter"},{name: "Alm",Alter: "26",Beruf: "PTA"},{name: "Chris",Alter: "18",Beruf: "AZUBI"},{name: "Smith",Alter: "4",Beruf: "OKA"} ]

function populateTable() {
  table.innerHTML = th
  table.innerHTML += schule.map(info =>
    `<tr> <td>   ${info.name} </td> <td> ${info.Alter}</td> <td> ${info.Beruf} </td> <td></td> </tr>`

  ).join('')
  document.querySelector("#reverss").addEventListener("click", samee);
}
populateTable();

function samee() {
  schule.pop();
  populateTable();
}
```

```html
<table>
</table>
```